# How to return a user input date as dd/mm/yyyy in Java?

Tags: java, date, arraylist, simpledateformat

A user needs to input a name, date, location etc of a task. The program is then meant to list each each task outputting the name, date, location etc.

When the user inputs a date, the format of the date is not what I need.

Example:

```
Enter a date: 21/07/2020
```

Output:

```
Tue Jul 21 00:00:00 AEST 2020
```

Desired output:

```
21/07/2020
```

Here is my code so far: - I am using multiple classes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Task{

private String theTitle;
private Date theDate;
private String theTime;
private String theLocation;
private String theDuration;
private String theCategory;
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Task(String title, Date date, String time, String location, String duration, String category) {
    
    theTitle = title;
    theDate = date;
    theTime = time;
    theLocation = location;
    theDuration = duration;
    theCategory = category;
    
}

public String getTitle() {
    
    return theTitle;
}

public Date getDate() {

    return theDate;
}

public String getTime() {
    
    return theTime;
}

public String getLocation() {
    
    return theLocation;
}

public String getDuration() {
    
    return theDuration;
}

public String getCategory() {
    
    return theCategory;
}

public String getItem() {
    
    return theTitle + ", " + theDate + ", " + theTime + ", " + theLocation + ", " + theDuration + ", " + theCategory;
}

}


public class ToDoList2 {

public Task myTaskObj;
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
private static List<String> currentList = new ArrayList<String>();

public ToDoList2() {
    
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws ParseException {
    
    ToDoList listObj = new ToDoList();
    
    int menuItem = -1;
    while (menuItem != 3) {
        menuItem = listObj.printMenu();
        switch (menuItem) {
        case 1:
            listObj.addItem();
            break;
        case 2:
            listObj.showList();
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        default:
            System.out.println("Enter a valid option");
        }
    }   
    
}

public int printMenu() {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("Main Menu");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("1. Add a task");
    System.out.println("2. List tasks");
    System.out.println("3. Leave the program");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
    
    return choice;
    
}

public void showList() {
System.out.println();
System.out.println("----------------------");       
System.out.println("To-Do List");
System.out.println("----------------------");
int number = 0;
for (String item : currentList) {
    System.out.println(++number + ". " + item);
}
System.out.println("----------------------");


}

public void addItem() throws ParseException {
System.out.println("Add a task");
System.out.println("----------------------");

System.out.print("Enter the task title: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String title = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the task date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
Date date=format.parse(scanner2.next());


System.out.print("Enter the task time: ");
Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
String time = scanner3.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the task location: ");
Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
String location = scanner4.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter the task duration (optional - press enter to skip): ");
Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
String duration = scanner5.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter the task category (optional - press enter to skip): ");
Scanner scanner6 = new Scanner(System.in);
String category = scanner6.nextLine();

myTaskObj = new Task(title, date, time, location, duration, category);

String theItem = myTaskObj.getItem();

currentList.add(theItem);
System.out.println("Task Added!");

    }
}
```

I am very new to java, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: The `Date` class is outdated. Use the `java.time` classes (particularly, here, `LocalDateTime`).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the simpleDateFormat but dont seem to have used it. It will specifically serve what you need.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(yourDate));
```

You need to add this logic inside

```
public String getItem() {
    
    return theTitle + ", " + sdf.format(theDate) + ", " + theTime + ", " + theLocation + ", " + theDuration + ", " + theCategory;
}
```

Since you hadnt specified anything there, it was calling the Date.toString() method while string concatenation.

Comment: Ok thanks. Where would I insert that into my code though? The date is output through the `getDate()` in the `Task` class

Comment: I dont see where are u printing. Can you tell me please

Comment: Got it. You need to add the logic inside getItem method. Please rename the simple date format object. I used sdf here for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [rich set of modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Define a formatter object:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

…and use that same [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object for both parsing and generating text.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter date in the format dd/MM/yyyy: ");
        String dateStr = scanner.nextLine();

        // Define a formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        // Parse the date string to LocalDate using the formatter
        LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);

        // Whenever you need to display it, display it using the same formatter
        String backToStr = formatter.format(theDate);
        System.out.println(backToStr);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter date in the format dd/MM/yyyy: 21/07/2020
21/07/2020
```

**A side note:** I can see that you have created a new instance of `Scanner` for every input. You should create just one instance of `Scanner` and use the same instance for every input.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code to get the correct format

```
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String formatedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```